# Postfix: which process is attempting to send to example.com?

Tags: email, postfix, centos-5

Here is the maillog extract:

```
May 15 10:20:41 nucleus postfix/smtp[4754]: connect to example.com[192.0.43.10]:25: Connection timed out
May 15 10:20:41 nucleus postfix/smtp[4755]: connect to example.com[192.0.43.10]:25: Connection timed out
May 15 10:20:41 nucleus postfix/smtp[4754]: 3DD566024C: to=<admin@example.com>, relay=none, delay=40615, delays=40585/0.02/30/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to example.com[192.0.43.10]:25: Connection timed out)
May 15 10:20:41 nucleus postfix/smtp[4755]: 414A66024E: to=<admin@example.com>, relay=none, delay=40615, delays=40585/0.02/30/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to example.com[192.0.43.10]:25: Connection timed out)
```

I understand what is happening here and I know how to treat this, I just need to know how I can find out which process is triggering this so that I can clean up the config files for that package.

```
postconf -d | grep mail_version
mail_version = 2.6.5
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried to read the content of the mail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had these same logs and I noticed these attempts were done right after each unsuccessful email sending from postfix.

When I saw these [postfix notification settings](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#notify_classes) I began to think that it has something to do with the default values.

I can't confirm as I didn't check, but I highly suspect it.